# GridsearchSV auto fill of params in Hyper parameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

Is there a way to do hyper parameter tuning with the use of [Gridsearch](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html?highlight=gridsearch#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) without defining each param (parameters) On a classifier/regressor? Like a auto hyper parameter tuning command. on documentation I found [ParameterGrid](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html) but I did not fully understand what this is for.

Comment: why downvote? can you explain it to me so I can know if my assumptions is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scikit-learn, you need to define both:

- which hyperparameter you want to tune
- which values of distributions you want to test for each hyperparameter

This is defined with a dictionary like `param_grid = {'C': [1, 10], 'kernel': ['linear', 'rbf]}` where the keys are the hyperparameter to be tuned, and the values are a list of values to be tested.
When you give this dictionary to `GridSearchCV`, it automatically creates a grid of hyperparameter with all possible combinations, using `ParameterGrid`. For example:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
param_grid = {'C': [1, 10], 'kernel': ['linear', 'rbf']}
list(ParameterGrid(param_grid)) == (
   [{'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}, {'C': 1, 'kernel': 'rbf'},
    {'C': 10, 'kernel': 'linear'}, {'C': 10, 'kernel': 'rbf'}])
```

This is the list of combinations of hyperparameters that are tested in the grid search.
See also [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-grid-search-digits-py) about how to use `GridSearchCV`, or the [Automatic parameter searches](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html#automatic-parameter-searches) section of the excellent [Getting-started guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html).

---

If you don't want to define yourself which hyperparameter to tune, or which values to test, you need an external definition of reasonable hyperparameter to tune that would work for any dataset. For example, you can take a look at "auto-ML" packages:

- [auto-sklearn](https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/)
  An automated machine learning toolkit and a drop-in replacement for a
  scikit-learn estimator.
- [autoviml](https://github.com/AutoViML/Auto_ViML/)
  Automatically Build Multiple Machine Learning Models with a Single Line of Code.
  Designed as a faster way to use scikit-learn models without having to preprocess data.
- [TPOT](https://github.com/rhiever/tpot)
  An automated machine learning toolkit that optimizes a series of scikit-learn
  operators to design a machine learning pipeline, including data and feature
  preprocessors as well as the estimators. Works as a drop-in replacement for a  scikit-learn estimator.
- [Featuretools](https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools)
  A framework to perform automated feature engineering. It can be used for
  transforming temporal and relational datasets into feature matrices for
  machine learning.
- [Neuraxle](https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle)
  A library for building neat pipelines, providing the right abstractions to
  both ease research, development, and deployment of machine learning
  applications. Compatible with deep learning frameworks and scikit-learn API,
  it can stream minibatches, use data checkpoints, build funky pipelines, and
  serialize models with custom per-step savers.
- [EvalML](https://github.com/alteryx/evalml)
  EvalML is an AutoML library which builds, optimizes, and evaluates
  machine learning pipelines using domain-specific objective functions.
  It incorporates multiple modeling libraries under one API, and
  the objects that EvalML creates use an sklearn-compatible API.